# Programming contest like input validator

Tags: python, regex, validation

I'm using an own framework for generate inputs, validate them and run a set of solutions over them to check if they are all the same. You can check that framework on https://bitbucket.org/danielmaxx/judge-tools.

By now it works OK, but I'm looking for a better way to define validators rather than using complex regular expressions. I'm thinking on using some sort of language for input specification, easier to write and much more legible. For those who don't know ACM-ICPC input standar, it's something like:

```
2
3 8
3
abc def ghi
4
8 44 6 6
2 45 96 20
21 4 64 14
6 66 78 12
```

Where that could be interpreted as "There will be a line with an integer N indicating the number of players. Next line will contain N integers indicating player's ages. Next line will contain an integer M indicating the possible names to pick, then, next line will contain M alphanumeric strings separated by spaces. Finally, a line with an integer K will indicate the relation matrix. Following K lines will contain K integers of the matrix's a_ij element."

Since reading that input can be programmed, I wonder if there is some library or utility (preferably in Python) to create data validators from descriptions of the input data in a non programmatic way.

Any suggestion will be welcome :)

Comment: it would be like (maybe)10 lines of python to validate that.... why do you need a library? also you fail to mention if this data is just being piped into sdtin? or is contained in a file like object or ??

Comment: Because when we do a contest, we may write 4 to 8 problems and some setters are not very skilled with Python regexes and we already experimented some problems with buggy validators in the past.
Inputs are not always the same, so every time a new problem is written, a new validator has to be written.

Comment: well if its not consistent than you are looking at a descriptive language there are lots of language toolkits ... but be forwarned this is not an easy path ...  take a look at ply as an example of a language definition language

Comment: edited my solution so it is more in line with what you want I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple framework I just wrote for you :)

```
class SizedInput(object):
    def __init__(self,label="input",map_fn=str):
        self.map_fn = map_fn
        self.label = label
        self._rval = None
    def _proc(self,sz,tokens):
        if len(tokens) < sz:
            msg = "Insufficient arguments for %s (expected %s got %s)"
            raise Exception(msg%(self.label,sz,len(tokens) )    )

        return (self.map_fn(x) for x in tokens[:sz]), tokens[sz:]
    def parse(self,input_tokens):
        sz = int(input_tokens[0])
        self._rval,rest = self._proc(sz,input_tokens[1:])
        return list(self._rval),rest
    def GetValue():
        return self._rval
    def __call__(self,input_tokens):
        return self.parse(input_tokens)

class MatrixInput(SizedInput):
    def _proc(self,sz,tokens):
        result, rest = SizedInput._proc(self,sz**2,tokens) #call super function with new size
        result = zip(*[iter(result)]*sz)  #this looks fancy but it just resizes 1d to 2d
            return result,rest          

def validateSchema(schema,input_tokens):
    rest = input_tokens
    results = {}
    for schema_item in schema:
        results[schema_item.label] ,rest = schema_item(rest)
    if rest:
        print "Warning : %d unconsumed tokens!"
    return results
```

to use it you must first create a schema to validate against

```
schema = [ #define a schema
    SizedInput("ages",int),
    SizedInput("names",str),
    MatrixInput("matrix",int),
]
```

then you need to tokenize your input data

```
input_stream = """
2 
8 9
3
asd dsa fff
2
1 2
3 4
"""
tokens = input_stream.split()
```

then you just need to pass it into your validator (first block of code), it will raise an exception if there is insufficient tokens, and print a warning if there are leftover tokens (you could easily change it to raise an exception)

```
print validateSchema(schema, tokens)
```

Comment: Ok, so this would allow people writing validators just to specify the schema and run validateSchema? This would be quite close (or maybe the most acurrate solution!) for what I want :D

Comment: yes, you may have to make different "input types", but yes essentially you would just specify a schema and then pass it the schema and token list and it would change the tokens into the desired inputs (did you run this example code?)

Comment: Yes, it runs nicely :D Thanks a lot Joran! I will improve this to make it fit to our needs :D